# why does python pep526 accept literals as the right hand side argument?

Tags: python, python-typing

Lazy copy-paste on my part I created something like:

```
state = {"foo":"bar"}

state["foo"]:"even more bar"
```

or even:

```
state["foo"]:2
```

This obviously is just a typo of the line that can arise easily if copying variables from if statements or dictionary literal bodies like:

```
state["foo"] = "even more bar"
```

Due to PEP 526 this is apparently seen as a valid type hint since 3.6 but it also is as discussed in other answers to this question a pernicious typo that can be very hard to uncover without explicit tests to check that the particular value in question changed after the assignment attempt.

Despite reading through PEP 526 I'm not especially clear on why the RHS of such a statement should ever accept a literal like this string or a float or int? It seems to be related to the difference between the local and class scope but that still doesn't make it any clearer why this doesn't raise an error at runtime? What is the use case for this? what is the reason why this shouldn't always raise some type of runtime error?

Comment: A literal string is how a forward reference to an as-yet-undefined type is specified.

Comment: but that still doesn't answer the question of why an int or float is accepted here

Comment: An annotation can be *any* expression. PEP 484 standardized what *should* be used; it did not change what *can* be used. (Annotations that aren't compatible with PEP 484 have been *deprecated*, but I don't know of any plans to actually drop support for arbitrary annotations.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python accepts type hints in the form of strings. If you come from a language like TypeScript, then:

```js
let str: "apple" | "banana"
let num: 0 | 1 | 2
```

The above code only allows the assignment of `"apple"` and `"banana"` to the string, or `0`, `1`, or `2` to the num variable.

**In Python, however, this is different.** In Python, you may use strings as type-hints to provide typings that haven't been defined yet. Take the following code:

```py
def create_instance() -> Apple
    return Apple("granny smith")

class Apple:
    def __init__(self, type: str):
        self.type = type
```

You will actually get a name error because when you reference the type hint (`-> Apple`) as the return type for `create_instance`, the `Apple` class hasn't been defined yet – and thus you cannot use it as a token.

The creators of Python type hints took this into account and decided to make a shotty solution that allows you to reference the `Apple` class as a type hint before it's declaration by converting it to a string. So using `-> "Apple"` will have the same meaning as `-> Apple`, but you're allowed to use it before the `Apple` class has been defined:

```py
def create_instance() -> "Apple"
    return Apple("granny smith")

class Apple:
    def __init__(self, type: str):
        self.type = type
```

Comment: thanks good explanation even if this feels like a pretty poor language "feature" that really just puts your code in the worst of all worlds. Seems to be of dubious usefulness while just creating a whole class of strange bugs.

The part of the question that remain unanswered to me is that in my testing this also worked when the right hand side is any other literal such as an int or float even though those would not make valid class names? Why is that?

for example:
`state['foo']:2`
seems to have the same behavior even though this would not be a valid class name

Comment: "You will actually get a syntax error" no, you will get a *runtime error*, a `NameError`, not a `SyntaxError` (which happens when the code is *parsed*)

Answer (score 1):

To quote [the Python language reference on `typing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html):

> Note: The Python runtime does not enforce function and variable type annotations. They can be used by third party tools such as type checkers, IDEs, linters, etc.

With its long tradition as an untyped language, automatically enforcing a static type system at any level would be an extremely disruptive change.

Ultimately, this means Python only checks for *syntactical* correctness of *annotations*. Their meaning and correctness as a type hint is not a concern of Python itself.
In short, Python must accept *any* syntactically valid expression as an annotation. Whether it is a type, or for that matter what even is a type, is out of scope for Python.

---

Notably, the static type system evolves separately from Python itself. For example, `typing_extensions` and quoting allow old Python versions to use typing features released much later – there is no problem in using, say, a v3.10 `ParamSpec` and the `|` union operator in Python 3.6 type hints.

Even an "obviously wrong" annotation could get some meaning in the future, for example `foo: 2` could conceivably become a shorthand for `foo: Literal[2]`. As such, Python *cannot* enforce type correctness or even just formal correctness of annotations.